# Multiple linear regression with categorical independent variables with subset function

Tags: r

I am trying to build my first multiple linear regression model. In this model, I am trying to know whether the dependent variable `meanf0` values are different across `VowelPositions` (independent variable) in just "disyllabic words" (disyllabic words are found in the `SyllableCount` variable, which contains two levels: "disyllabic" and "trisyllabic") and in a specific `SyllabicType` "open"(SyllabicType is another independent predictor variable that contains two levels: "open" and "closed").
I am stuck on how to build a model with just some categories of given independent variable if that is possible? here is my tentative model:

```r
model_F0_disyll <- lm (data=QP1_subset_norm,     
                       meanf0_norm~SyllableCount+ syllableType+VowelPosition,
                       subset(SyllableCount=="2" & syllableType=="open"))
```

but it does seem to work.

Comment: it works or it does NOT? also if you want to check whether there is a subsequent mean difference between the groups, just do an `aov` summary on your model. You do not have to subset the data

Comment: @onyambu Thank you for your comment! I am not sure by running ANOVA, I can know if the differences in the mean F0 is compared across the groups (vowel positions) in disyllabic or trisyllabic. I would like to separate theses two categories

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need something like:

```r
model_F0_disyll <- lm (data=QP1_subset_norm,     
                       meanf0_norm~SyllableCount+ syllableType+VowelPosition,
                       subset = (SyllableCount==2 & syllableType=="open"))
```

The `subset` argument is just the expression used to make the subset, you don't need to call the `subset()` function.  Further, when the variable is numeric (presumably like `SyllableCount`, you could use either a numeric or string value.  That is `SyllableCount == "2"` and `SyllableCount == 2` both work.

Here's an example with the `mtcars` data:

```r
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data=mtcars, subset=(am == "1" & cyl == 4))
summary(mod)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ hp + wt, data = mtcars, subset = (am == "1" & 
#>     cyl == 4))
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Datsun 710       Fiat 128    Honda Civic Toyota Corolla      Fiat X1-9 
#>       -2.66851        4.18787       -2.61455        3.25523       -2.62538 
#>  Porsche 914-2   Lotus Europa     Volvo 142E 
#>       -0.77799        1.17181        0.07154 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 47.24552    6.57304   7.188 0.000811 ***
#> hp          -0.07288    0.05695  -1.280 0.256814    
#> wt          -6.46508    3.15205  -2.051 0.095512 .  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.193 on 5 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.6378, Adjusted R-squared:  0.493 
#> F-statistic: 4.403 on 2 and 5 DF,  p-value: 0.07893
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! to answer some of your comments: 1) "SyllableCount" is not numeric. I just coded disyllabic by "2" and trisyllabic by "3"( I factorised it before i ran the model). 2) good info to know about the subset point.

Comment: @DalGa Your model is too poor. You should consider another model

Comment: @onyambu I'm not sure how you can know the quality of the model since we've not been given the data or the output.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong OP had previously commented with the model results having a R^2 of 0.2 or 0.02 i dont remember

Comment: @DaveArmstrong I tried to comment on your answer with the results I got using the "answer my question" option. Thank you!